# Filtering rows with at least two different values across selected columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

For example my data looks like this (actual dataset has 10,000+ rows):

| ID | 1160 | 1160 | 1216 | 1216 | 1132 | 1132 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | T | T | T | T | T | T |
| 02 | T | T | T | T | T | G |
| 03 | A | G | NA | NA | A | A |
| 04 | I | I | I | I | I | I |
| 05 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 06 | G | G | G | G | G | G |

The result I am expecting is:

| ID | 1160 | 1160 | 1216 | 1216 | 1132 | 1132 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02 | T | T | T | T | T | G |
| 03 | A | G | NA | NA | A | A |

Comment: WHat does "at leas[t] one column has different allele" mean?

Comment: My bad, I want to filter the rows that meet the above criteria I have mentioned.

Comment: So in the example table, if you see the row with ID 02 that has all T's except for 1132 which has a G. I want to pick that kind of rows.

Comment: So rows where at least one pair of columns is different.

Answer (score 4):

Vectorized base solution using `rowSums`:

```
dat[rowSums(dat[,-(1:2)] != dat[,2], na.rm = TRUE) > 0,]
#>   ID X1160 X1160.1 X1216 X1216.1 X1132 X1132.1
#> 2 02     T       T     T       T     T       G
#> 3 03     A       G  <NA>    <NA>     A       A
```

Data thanks to @SamR:

```
dat  <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, `1160` = c("T", "T", "A", "I", NA, "G"
), `1160` = c("T", "T", "G", "I", NA, "G"), `1216` = c("T", "T", 
NA, "I", NA, "G"), `1216` = c("T", "T", NA, "I", NA, "G"), `1132` = c("T", 
"T", "A", "I", NA, "G"), `1132` = c("T", "G", "A", "I", NA, "G"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Excellent solution and super fast +1.

Answer (score 2):

You could count the number of unique values and keep the rows where there is more than one.

```r
dat[
    sapply(data.frame(t(dat[, -1])), \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) > 1),
]
  ID 1160 1160 1216 1216 1132 1132
2  2    T    T    T    T    T    G
3  3    A    G <NA> <NA>    A    A
```

Or if you want a `dplyr` method you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat  |>
    rowwise()  |>
    filter(n_distinct(na.omit(c_across(X1160:X1132.1))) > 1)
```

I suspect this will be much slower. Also, I've used `check.names = TRUE` to fix the column names in this example because you had duplicates.

##### Data

```r
dat  <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, `1160` = c("T", "T", "A", "I", NA, "G"
), `1160` = c("T", "T", "G", "I", NA, "G"), `1216` = c("T", "T", 
NA, "I", NA, "G"), `1216` = c("T", "T", NA, "I", NA, "G"), `1132` = c("T", 
"T", "A", "I", NA, "G"), `1132` = c("T", "G", "A", "I", NA, "G"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This worked for the most part, but it is considered NA as a unique value, so if any of the rows have the same alleles in all the columns but there is one NA column, it is considered that as a unique count. Can we fix this?

Comment: @sai sure I just added in `na.omit()`

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply`, subset for rows where `length(unique(na.omit(.)))` is greater than 1. Note, that `apply` (unlike `lapply, sapply`) is designed for matrices so use `as.matrix` (see benchmark).

```
> dat[apply(as.matrix(dat[, -1]), 1, \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) > 1),]
  ID X1160 X1160.1 X1216 X1216.1 X1132 X1132.1
2 02     T       T     T       T     T       G
3 03     A       G  <NA>    <NA>     A       A
```

Alternatively using `data.table` approaches, but they're slower.

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(dat)
> ss <- DT[, apply(.SD, 1, \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) > 1L), .SDcols=-"ID"]
> DT[ss]
   ID X1160 X1160.1 X1216 X1216.1 X1132 X1132.1
1: 02     T       T     T       T     T       G
2: 03     A       G  <NA>    <NA>     A       A


> dat[dat[, .I[uniqueN(unlist(.SD)) > 1], by = ID]$V1]
   ID X1160 X1160.1 X1216 X1216.1 X1132 X1132.1
1: 02     T       T     T       T     T       G
2: 03     A       G  <NA>    <NA>     A       A
```

### Benchmark

```
> set.seed(42)
> dat <- dat[sample.int(nrow(dat), 1e4, replace=TRUE), c(1, sample(2:7, 100, replace=TRUE))]
> dat$ID <- seq_len(nrow(dat))
> dim(dat)
[1] 10000   101
> library(data.table)
> DT <- copy(dat)
> setDT(DT)
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(DT_apply=DT[DT[, apply(.SD, 1, \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) > 1), .SDcols=-"ID"]],
+                                uniqueN=DT[DT[, .I[uniqueN(unlist(.SD)) > 1], by = ID]$V1],
+                                sapply=dat[sapply(data.frame(t(dat[, -1])), \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) > 1), ], 
+                                apply1=dat[apply(as.matrix(dat)[, -1], 1, \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) > 1),],
+                                apply2=dat[apply(dat[, -1], 1, \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) > 1), ], 
+                                rowSums=dat[rowSums(dat[,-(1:2)] != dat[,2], na.rm = TRUE) > 0,],
+                                check='equivalent', times=3L)
```

```
$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
[1] 10000   101
Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
  DT_apply 294.37968 303.13732 319.45124 311.89496 331.98702 352.0791     3 a  
   uniqueN 500.26405 506.89700 525.72478 513.52995 538.45514 563.3803     3  b 
    sapply 272.91508 275.14036 282.03352 277.36564 286.59273 295.8198     3 a  
    apply1 268.85171 302.18075 313.40154 335.50978 335.67645 335.8431     3 a  
    apply2 260.46164 263.21591 266.25917 265.97017 269.15793 272.3457     3 a  
   rowSums  92.66537  93.14489  97.21008  93.62441  99.48244 105.3405     3   c *
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(ID = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"), X1160 = c("T", 
"T", "A", "I", NA, "G"), X1160.1 = c("T", "T", "G", "I", NA, 
"G"), X1216 = c("T", "T", NA, "I", NA, "G"), X1216.1 = c("T", 
"T", NA, "I", NA, "G"), X1132 = c("T", "T", "A", "I", NA, "G"
), X1132.1 = c("T", "G", "A", "I", NA, "G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having duplicate column names is not a great idea. I have used `janitor::clean_names()` to get unique column names.

In `dplyr` we can use `if_all` or `across` to `filter` based on multiple columns. See below:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  filter(!if_all(x1160:x1132_2, ~ if_else(is.na(.x), TRUE, .x == x1160)))

#>   id x1160 x1160_2 x1216 x1216_2 x1132 x1132_2
#> 1  2     T       T     T       T     T       G
#> 2  3     A       G  <NA>    <NA>     A       A
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>